# What autocmd event is triggered when we move cursor to window?

Tags: vim

What event is triggered when we move between open windows (splits) using `CTRL-W W`?

```
                                                *CTRL-W_W*
CTRL-W W        Without count: move cursor to window above/left of current
            one.  If there is no window above or left, go to bottom-right
            window.  With count: go to Nth window (windows are numbered
            from top-left to bottom-right).
```

I used `BufEnter`, `BufWinEnter`, `FocusGained`, `WinEnter`, `CmdwinEnter`, `TabEnter`. But none of them are triggering the autocommand.

For now, I'm forced to `alt-tab` between windows to reliably trigger the `autocommand`.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your state. Try `vim -u NONE +vsp +"au WinEnter * echo 'YO'"` then press Ctrl-W W; you should see `YO` at the bottom of the screen. If you don't, you have a weird Vim. If you do, try without `-u NONE`. If you now don't, a plugin (or a vimrc setting) is interfering.

Comment: Alt-tab doesn't allow you to switch between "open windows (splits)"; only between GUI windows and thus Vim instances. It looks like there's a rather large root issue of comprehension, here.

Comment: Please add an example of how you use these autocommands

Comment: @amadan, I was able to get the the `YO` printed **with** and **without** `-u NONE`.

@romainl, I am not trying to Alt-tab between splits. Thats the work around I have to do to trigger the `au` that I want.

@yolenoyer, the `au` that I have is 

`au BufEnter,BufWinEnter,FocusGained,WinEnter,CmdwinEnter,TabEnter * if (expand('%:h') != '') | cd %:h | endif`

Comment: If you can use `WinEnter` with `-u NONE` and can't without it, then you need to find which of your settings/plugins is messing things up for you.

Answer (score 4):

The correct event is `WinEnter`. If that doesn't work for you (with plugins enabled), check the `'eventignore'` option.

Comment: I checked. But `eventignore` setting is empty.